# Alternatives to Android Studio Emulator to test App

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I don't know how the StackOverFlow community will take this, but I'm going ask any way..

I recently started learning Kotlin and Android Studio, less than 2 weeks ago. I can't seem to run my code in android studio and, my laptop USB port is always shaking so I can't run it successful using my device.

This is disturbing to me since for the past 5 months I've been working on a project with `KivyMD`, which I've completed, and I discovered Google no longer accepts `APKs` and I'm using a HP laptop which is not ideal for Kivy developers, due to difficulty in packaging, and many other road blocks..
That's why I'm learning `Kotlin`, I know you might not really care, but I hope as a fellow developer you understand..

So my **Question**, is there an alternative to running my app on Android Studio Emulator and device testing..

I'd be really thankful for any suggestion or contribution, Thanks :)

Comment: Option a) Connect your android device over Wi-Fi with [ADB over Wi-Fi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+). b) Use a remote android device for example from [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/mobile-testing-lab) or a smiliar service.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Thanks a lot for your suggestions I'll try them out and let you know how it went..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download this plugging ADB WIFI
[image]

you only connect once to the usb and voila, a great pluggin.